# Ubable to connect to remote MySQL via db-mysql (node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I wrote a small `node.js` code to try and insert stuff to my remote MySQL server but I keep getting the following error:

```
CONNECTION error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '**********.com' (60)
```

I tried writing a `PHP` script for the same and it worked for the same `hostname` and `database`. Am I missing something? Here is my `node.js` code:

```
var mysql = require('db-mysql');
new mysql.Database({
    hostname: '*********.com',
    user: '**********',
    password: '*********',
    database: '**********'
}).connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('CONNECTION error: ' + error);
    }
    this.query().
        insert('MainUserDatabase',
            ['email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
            ['xyzh@gmail.com', 'password', 'Oeem', 'Stosh']
        ).
        execute(function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                        console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
                        return;
                }
                console.log('GENERATED id: ' + result.id);
        });
});
```

Comment: This look's like it should be working. I see no error in comparison to my db-mysql code I'm using.
Do you connect to a different port ? And did the php script was executed on the same machine as the node is running ?

Comment: @cb0: No, the PHP script was uploaded to the server. It was not from the same machine. How do I change the port?

Comment: Just set a "port:" option where you specified the hostname, user, etc.